# How to assign a string to struct variable in C?

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, c-strings, assignment-operator

> I am unable to figure out how to assign a string to a struct variable using only **<stdio.h>** header file.

The following code gives me an error and I am unable to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 struct Student
{
    char name[50];
};
int main()
{
   struct Student s1;
   printf("Enter studen's name:\n");
   scanf("%s",s1.name);
   printf("Name : \n",s1.name);
   s1.name={"Hussain"};
   printf("Name : \n",s1.name);
}
```

It gives the following error while compilation:

```
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:12:12: error: expected expression before '{' token
    s1.name={"Hussain"};
            ^
```

I have tried initializing it in the following way:
`s1.name="Hussain";`
But this doesn't work too.
I could avoid this by the use of pointers as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 struct Student
{
    char *name;
};
int main()
{
   struct Student s1;
   printf("Enter studen's name:\n");
   scanf("%s",s1.name);
   printf("Name : %s\n",s1.name);
   s1.name="Hussain";
   printf("Name : %s\n",s1.name);
}
```

This code works perfectly fine with no errors.
But I want to know where exactly I am doing wrong with the array, which is making my code not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays do not have the assignment operator. So these assignment statements

```
s1.name = { "Hussain" };
s1.name = "Hussain";
```

are invalid.

You could use the standard C string function `strcpy` to copy elements of the string literal to the array `s1.name` like

```
#include <string.h>

//...

strcpy( s1.name, "Hussain" );
```

If you may not use standard string functions then you need to write a loop as for example

```
const char *p = "Hussain";

for ( char *t = s1.name; ( *t++ = *p++ ) != '\0'; );
```

Or

```
for ( char *t = s1.name, *p = "Hussain"; ( *t++ = *p++ ) != '\0'; );
```

Pay attention to that the second your program has undefined behavior. The pointer `s1.name` is not initialized and does not point to a valid object of an array type. So the call of `scanf` in this code snippet invokes undefined behavior.

```
struct Student s1;
printf("Enter studen's name:\n");
scanf("%s",s1.name);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for making things crystal clear!

Answer (score 4):

A char array (and arrays in general) can't be assigned a value directly, only initialized.  To write a string into a char array, use `strcpy`.

```
strcpy(s1.name, "Hussain");
```

The latter code where the `name` member is a pointer works for the assignment because the pointer is assigned the start address of the start of the string constant.  Also note that you can't (at least not yet) use `strcpy` in that case because `s1.name` doesn't point anywhere.  You would first need to allocate memory using `malloc`, or perform both steps at once using `strdup`.  Also for this reason, you can't yet use `scanf` until you allocate memory.

If you're not allowed to use functions from string.h, then you would need to write the characters into the array one at a time, and then write a terminating null byte at the end.

Comment: oh.. so basically we have to do it this way.

Comment: "using only **<stdio.h>** ..."

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use `<string.h>`, then you have to implement your own version of `strcpy()`:

```c
void copystring(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    const char *p = src;
    while (*p) {
        *dest = *p;
        p++;
        dest++;
    }
    *dest = '\0'; // Null-terminate string (as pointed by @Ted)
}
```

Make sure that `dest` has enough space to hold `src`.

Also, avoid using `scanf()` in your code. Use `fgets()` as an alternative.

**EDIT:** As pointed by Jabberwocky, `fgets()` leaves `\n` read in the string. But since using `<string.h>` is not allowed, you have to implement your own function to replace it with a null-terminator:

```c
int findchar(const char *str, char c)
{
    int pos;
    for (pos = 0; str[pos]; ++pos)
        if (str[pos] == c)
            return pos;
    
    return -1;
}
```

You can use it like:

```c
char str[100];
if (!fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) {
    // fgets() failed. Do something.
} else {
    int nwln = findchar(str, '\n');
    if (nwln == -1) {
        // You probably entered more than 100 characters
        // because \n couldn't be found.
    } else {
        str[nwln] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Comment: However `fgets` comes with its own problem. It leaves a `\n` at the end of the string which must likely must be taken care of. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input

Comment: This doesn't look like it'll null terminate `dest`. You could just add `*dest = '\0';` after the loop - or copy the null terminator in the loop too. Here's an alternative that [copies _at most_ `count`](https://godbolt.org/z/zc68bbof6) characters.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I know. I just skipped this point to keep the answer short. I've updated my answer anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I've udpated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Zakk [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) is in `<stdio.h>`, not `<string.h>`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I know. I am talking about `strcpy()` and `strcspn()` which are in `<string.h>`